# How to hide div then show another div on click using toggle_visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want show div 1 on html load while hiding div 2, then using onclick I want to exchange their visibility like when clicking button hide div1 then show div2, then when clicking again, hide div2 then show div 1. Here is my code:

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'none')
          e.style.display = 'block';
       else
          e.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Hide DIV 1 show DIV 2</a>
<div id="foo"> This is  DIV 1</div></div>
<div id="foo"> This is  DIV 2</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Initially set your `div1` to `display:none;` and simply toggle them. 
 I have used class `targetElement` just to get rid of common selector. `hidden` class is used to use the default `style` `display:none;` and to replace the `inline-style`.

I woul like to use  `button` instead of  `<a href="#">Click here</a>`. to do this simple replace a tag  with `<button type="button"> Button Name </button>`

```js
$('#toggleButton').on('click',function(){
 $('.targetElement').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden{
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="toggleButton" href="#">Click here</a>
<div id="foo" class="targetElement hidden"> This is  DIV 1</div></div>
<div id="foo" class="targetElement"> This is  DIV 2</div></div>
```

Comment: Great answer. Making use of Jquery to make the code easier. One thing I would say is that adding the event listener on all the "a" tags can cause some issues in a real scenario. I would suggest adding an ID to the a tag and adding the event listener on that a tag only.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to have 2 elements with the same ID. ID's should always be unique. Use classes instead. To hide a div onload. Simply add the css to your html element in a `style` attribute. You also had unecessary `</div>` tags that I removed.

Here is working code using JQuery (less code) :

```js
$("#toggle").on("click", function() {
  $(".isToggable").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="toggle" href="#" >Hide DIV 1 show DIV 2</a>
  <div class="isToggable"> This is DIV 1</div>
  <div class="isToggable" style="display:none"> This is DIV 2</div>
```

In the html, I added classes to elements that you want to be toggled. I also added an ID to the `a` tag. In the JQuery I added an event listener onclick on that `a` tag using it's ID. `$(".isToggable").toggle();` takes all the elements with the class "isToggable" in the page toggles their visibility.

> With no parameters, the .toggle() method simply toggles the visibility of elements

More information on toggle : [JQuery Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

---

### Old answer (vanilla javascript)

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var container = document.getElementById(id);

  for (var i = 0; i < container.children.length; i++) {
    let currentElem = container.children[i];
    if (currentElem.style.display === "none") {
      currentElem.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      currentElem.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('container');">Hide DIV 1 show DIV 2</a>
<div id="container">
  <div> This is DIV 1</div>
  <div style="display:none"> This is DIV 2</div>
</div>
```

How this works is you put your elements that you want to toggle the visibility inside a container and the `toggle_visibility` function will toggle all the visibilities of the elements inside. That way if you decide to add more div's they will all be handled.

If you have any questions on how this works. Don't hesitate to ask. Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

The attribute [*id*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) must be unique in a document. Use [*class*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) instead.

First use CSS to hide the second div. Then use `forEach()` to hide/show div. You should also avoid using inline event handler.

Try the following way:

```js
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click',function(){
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.foo'), function(el){
    if(el.style.display == 'none')
        el.style.display = 'block';
     else
        el.style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#">Hide DIV 1 show DIV 2</a>
<div class="foo"> This is  DIV 1</div></div>
<div class="foo" style="display:none;"> This is  DIV 2</div></div>
```

Comment: @NTR, which version of IE you are talking about?

Comment: IE 11. It does not support forEach in that syntax.

Comment: it did not fix it. Suggested an edit with code that works on IE 11.